# php spit string after x char but only on period

Tags: php, string, split

I have a string of 5000 char and I want to split it in small chunks of 200 char, split_str() function does that but I would like the strings chopped at the last full stop in the string rather than cutting a word or sentence in half.

here is an example:

```
<?php
$str = '<h1>Samsung Z4. smartphone com Tizen. pode estar perto de ser lançado em novo país<h1>';
$arr = str_split($str, 20);

?>
```

OutPut is:

```
Samsung Z4. smartpho
```

But i need it to be smart and give me  just 'Samsung Z4.'

Comment: You need to add an input and an expected output as well as your code that converts it.

Comment: I don't have a code yet, I was hoping if I could find an str function for it.

Comment: added an example

Comment: I think you would need to find the first period with str_pos and then split on that.

Comment: You want to include HTML tags as well?

Comment: Yes, HTML tags are there in the string too

Comment: @mkaatman Your solution worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$last_space = strpos($str, '. ',4000);
$next_part = substr($str, $last_space);
//var_dump($next_part);
$my_part = substr($str, 0 ,$last_space);
//var_dump($my_part);
$array[] =  $my_part;
$str = $next_part;
}
while($last_space);
array_push($array,$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop with strpos.  Ensure the period you find is followed by two spaces and then a capital letter (assuming that's your rule for "last full stop in the string), add that to your array of sentences and continue.

Here's a super simple implementation that does what you requested in the comments:

```
<?php
$str = "Samsung Z4. smartphone com Tizen. pode estar perto de ser lançado em novo país";
$sentences = array();
$sentences = explode(".", $str);
echo $sentences[0];
```

Comment: can you please write an example for that, i edited the question with a bit of a code

Comment: See my updated answer.  Please mark as correct and upvote if satisfactory.

Comment: I got the overall idea from your answer but it does not satisfy the condition of char limit I am intending to apply as well on the same string as a filter.

Comment: Loop through the $sentences array again and for strings that are longer than your max, break them up.